# building busybox including kernel headers, what files to include

Tags: linux, build, header, embedded-linux, busybox

I'm using linux3.3 and recently while building busybox for a new command, found the added busybox source file uses linux kernel headers.

So I looked up the internet and did 'make headers_install ARCH=.. CROSS_COMPILE=.. INSTALL_HDR_PATH=..' to extract headers usable for the user space program.

Then I used the new header files instead of files under sparc-snake-linux/sys-include.

But I had to copy over some missing files from the sys-include to the new header directories and had to copy some missing definitions from the sys-include files to the corresponing file in the new header files.(somewhere on the internet I read this 'make headers_install' was not upgraded after linux2.6 or so)

Is this what I am supposed to do? (why are there some missing files? I geuss it's because the 'make headers_install' is not well-maintained and doesn't work well for versions later than 2.6? Am I correct?)

Using this method, I have removed tens of 'undefined' errors but now I see some definitions conflict between files from sparc-snake-linux/sys-include (of course new cleaned and beefed-up version) and sparc-snake-linux/include. What version should be used?

And if I succeed compilation(by fixing header problems), do I have to build the glibc again with this new header files? (I'm afraid it's so. I'm using glibc for busybox)

any help would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks

Chan

ADD : I've extracted the new header files using above command and built busybox with new added command(route and other IP related functions). It works fine and the reason it didn't work was I had the variable *KERNEL* defined for busybox which should not be done(because busybox is not kernel code, but user program).

Comment: in http://kernelnewbies.org/KernelHeaders it says, "the correct way to package the header files for a distribution is to run 'make headers_install' from the kernel source directory to install the headers into /usr/include and then rebuild the C library package, with a dependency on the specific version of the just installed kernel headers. " So I guess I have to rebuild the C library package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've extracted the new header files using above command and built busybox with new added command(route and other IP related functions). It works fine and the reason it didn't work was I stupidly had the variable _KERNEL_ defined for a while for busybox which should not be done(because busybox is not kernel code, but user program).
when you use
echo "" | arch-abc-linux-gcc -o /tmp/tmp.o -v -x c -
you can see what the standard include path is. If the cross compiler is for compiling application on linux (like the one above), it will have linux system header path in the standard include path. Replace that with the new extracted header path. What I did was to use -nostdinc option and provide include path explicitly.